# How do I get points to buy things in "My Baby 3 & Friends"?

Tags: my-baby-3-and-friends

My daughter is playing the Nintendo DSi game "My Baby 3 & Friends" and she is frustrated that she doesn't have points to 'buy' accessories in the game. Apparently you are supposed to be able to take pictures in the game and "send them to grandma" for points, but the "send a picture" options in the game are always grayed-out. What is the secret to get points in this game?

Comment: *waits to see who takes the bait...* :)

Comment: Hem...  1st April is only in 2 months from now.

Comment: @Anto hey hey, this is a serious question about a video game.  Are you pro enough to answer and get the bounty?

Comment: According to an Amazon review, "the My Baby series is even better than HALO". Surely someone is capable of going into a game store, buying this game, answering the question, and then trading it back in (or not, this game is supposed to be 'great').

Comment: Since the original poster hasn't been around here for a while... who will be able to corroborate an answer if one does come up? I was actually wondering about some things and wanted to post a comment, but then realized this question was 7 months old.

Comment: He's still active on a different stack though, maybe we could get him to answer if he ever figured it out?

Comment: @Aubergine you can back up your answer with a source or a posted game play video and earn the bounty regardless if the original querent accepts your answer.

Comment: This is a serious question about a real game. Its true I don't hang out here, but I do get notified when someone touches this - I just noticed that this comments occurred. :) I just asked her if she figured it out, and she described the same steps shown below, so I think @Aubergine nailed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine that in order to send a picture to grandma you first need to take one. While I couldn't find the specific procedure for My Baby 3 & Friends, I did stumble across [this QA list](http://www.cheatmasters.com/qa/26190/My_Baby_Boy_qa.html) for another game in the same series, [My Baby Boy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Baby_%28series%29#My_Baby_Girl.2FMy_Baby_Boy), where it says:

> **Q:** How do I get to take a picture with the camera so I can send
>   pictures and get stars for it? 
> **A:** You either press the L or the R
>   button and a screen will come up. Click L or R again then the photo
>   you've taken will show up on the top screen. On the bottom screen it
>   will say Give to Grandma or Give to Shop. Send it to the shop for
>   stars but send it to Grandma for Presents.

Since its a game from the same series and the mechanics seem amazingly similar, I suspect this would also work for the game in question.

Comment: nice, I'm going to give bruce 2 days to respond before I reward the bounty

Comment: Thanks for offering the bounty - I don't have the rep here to do that yet.